# Fundamental theorem for Malliavin derivative and Lebesgue integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

I am interested in some kind of fundamental theorem of calculus for the Malliavin derivative: My notations are mainly taken from the Book Nualart: The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics.

Let $u\in\mathbb L^{1,2}$, i.e. a stochastic process which is Malliavin differentiable for every $t\geq0$. Let moreover be $T\in\mathbb D^{1,2}$ a Malliavin differentiable non-negative random variable. How can I calculate $D_u\int_0^{T(\omega)}u_s(\omega)\;\mathrm ds$?

I am also interested in any literature for this problem.

Comment: Did you end up finding a answer to this?

Comment: @CSA No, I found no answer on this. I solved my problem in a different way. But I would still be interested if you have some ideas.

Comment: unfortunately not I simply had a very similar problem.